# groupby and get min then append values of the min row

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I use groupby and then minimum as aggregation function. I need some other values of the row with the minimum value. In the following MWE, I need `City` value of the row with the minimum distance `mindist`.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'City' : ['London', 'Paris', 'Lyon','NY', 'Bristol'], 'Distance' : [5, 1, 7, 2, 6], 'Country':['UK','FR','FR','US','UK']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df['mindist']=df.groupby(['Country'])['Distance'].transform(min)
print(df)


      City  Distance Country
0   London         5      UK
1    Paris         1      FR
2     Lyon         5      FR
3       NY         2      US
4  Bristol         6      UK
```

I want to append the `City` value according to aggregated `mindist` as follows:

```
      City  Distance Country  mindist City1
0   London         5      UK        5 London
1    Paris         1      FR        1 Paris
2     Lyon         5      FR        1 Paris
3       NY         2      US        2 NY
4  Bristol         6      UK        5 London
```

Note that there can be duplicate values in the `Distance` column.

Comment: @PaulBrennan `mindist` is obtained when data is grouped by `Country`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Distance` with `City` `Series`:

```
df['City1'] = df['mindist'].map(df.set_index('Distance')['City'])
print(df)
      City  Distance Country  mindist   City1
0   London         5      UK        5  London
1    Paris         1      FR        1   Paris
2     Lyon         7      FR        1   Paris
3       NY         2      US        2      NY
4  Bristol         6      UK        5  London
```